# Add exclusion filters for Nginx, all logs which are OKAY, Debug, Trace shouldn't be added

Tags: nginx, datadog

I am deploying Nginx via Helm chart, and looking to exclude all the OKAY, Debug logs via DataDog filters. DataDog has some good links [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/) but none of them cover the use-case for Nginx, which doesn't have a severity attached to its logs. I would like to skip all logs from DataDog which just say they are okay. How can I do that?

Current code:

```yaml
    podAnnotations:
      ad.datadoghq.com/tags: '{"source": "nginx-ingress-controller"}'
      ad.datadoghq.com/controller.logs: >-
        [{
          "log_processing_rules": [{
             "type": "exclude_at_match",
              "name": "exclude-nginx-ingress-access-logs",
              "pattern" : ""upstream_status\":\"200\""
         }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be missing an escape to the first double quote.
Maybe that's the issue?

Updated code:

```
podAnnotations:
  ad.datadoghq.com/tags: '{"source": "nginx-ingress-controller"}'
  ad.datadoghq.com/controller.logs: >-
    [{
      "log_processing_rules": [{
         "type": "exclude_at_match",
          "name": "exclude-nginx-ingress-access-logs",
          "pattern" : "\"upstream_status\":\"200\""
     }
    }]
```